# Rotating an entire axes in Matlab Guide

Tags: matlab, rotation, matlab-guide

I am currently trying to rotate an entire axes named axes1.

```
                imr=imrotate(img,30);
                axes(this.gui_h.axes1);
                imshow(imr,'Parent',this.gui_h.axes1);
```

The code above initiates a rotation of 30 degrees. However, the image is rotated but not the entire axes1. I have tested guide tools such as the rotate3D, however rotate3D does not work successfully for 2d images. I have also tried  `set(handles.axes1,'Rotation',-25);` , which has no effect. It simply overlooks the statement and continues with the other tasks. Is there a way to rotate the entire axes?

Comment: You can use: `I = imrotate(frame2im(getframe(gca)), 30);`, but the rotation is only visual (result is an image, not a functional axes).

Comment: its seems to rotate just the image withing the axes, not the axes. In addition to that the image is represented as a white square with a black background

Comment: The reason why I want to rotate the entire axes than just the image within the axes, is because rotating the axes would not change size of the image as it rotates. Rotating the image in an axes alters the size. If there is a way to work around this, it can also be an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [view](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) functin to rotate the axes.

```
imshow('Jupiter_New_Horizons.jpg')
xlabel('X axis')
ylabel('Y axis')
camzoom(.8)

% Rotate the axes changing the Azimuth value
for i=0:-3:-180
   view([i 90]);
   pause(.3)
end
```

[image]

This also applies to standard plots:

```
t=0:.1:2*pi;
x=sin(t)
plot(t,x);
grid minor
xlabel('X axis')
ylabel('Y axis')
camzoom(.8)
for i=0:-3:-180
   view([i 90]);
   pause(.3)
end
```

[image]

**Edit following the comments**

I've created a simple GUI with two `axes` and two `pushbutton` with the following `tag`

- axes #1: axes1
- axes #2: axes2
- pushbutton #1: pushbutton1
- pushbutton #2: pushbutton2

The `callback` of *pushbutton1* loads an image in the *axes1*, the turns the axes.

The `callback` of *pushbutton2* plots a curve in the *axes2*, the turns the axes.

The GUI works properly, the axers rotates as expected.

This is the `.m` of the GUI; you can test it creating the GUI and using the `tag` as specified above.

```
function varargout = fbdfi(varargin)
% FBDFI MATLAB code for fbdfi.fig
%      FBDFI, by itself, creates a new FBDFI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = FBDFI returns the handle to a new FBDFI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      FBDFI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in FBDFI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      FBDFI('Property','Value',...) creates a new FBDFI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before fbdfi_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to fbdfi_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help fbdfi

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 26-Feb-2017 20:56:22

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @fbdfi_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @fbdfi_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before fbdfi is made visible.
function fbdfi_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to fbdfi (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for fbdfi
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes fbdfi wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = fbdfi_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

imshow('Jupiter_New_Horizons.jpg','parent',handles.axes1)
xlabel(handles.axes1,'X axis')
ylabel(handles.axes1,'Y axis')
camzoom(handles.axes1,.8)

for i=0:-10:-180
   view(handles.axes1,[i 90]);
   pause(.3)

end

% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

t=0:.1:2*pi;
x=sin(t)
plot(handles.axes2,t,x);
grid minor
xlabel(handles.axes2,'X axis')
ylabel(handles.axes2,'Y axis')
camzoom(handles.axes2,.8)
for i=0:-10:-180
   view(handles.axes2,[i 90]);
   pause(.3)
end
```

[image]

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: Thank you it does rotate. However, I have two axes displayed in the figure.  `[a,b]=uigetfile(['*.*','All Files']);
              img=imread([b a]);
              [r3,c3]=size(img)
              img = rgb2gray(img);
              imshow(img,'Parent',this.gui_h.axes1);                                                                                          camzoom(.8)

                % Rotate the axes changing the Azimuth value
                for i=0:-3:-180
                   view([i 90]);
                   pause(.3)
                end`

Comment: The code rotates the next axes which has no image. When I try to load an image in axes2, it does not load. Is there a way to specific the axes eg: handles.axes1 or handles.axes2

Comment: You can try specifying the handle of the axes you want to rotate in the call to `view` (e. g. `view(axes_handle,[i 90])`.

Comment: Thank you I updated to `view(this.gui_h.axes1,[i 90]);` . However, it completely disappears from the gui/figure. Am I missing a step?

Comment: I've created a simple GUI with two `axes` and two `pushbuttons`: one pushbuttons load the image and turns the axes, the other plot a curve in the other axes and turns it. It works, the axes rotate correctl. The code for the plot and the rotation is in the `pushbutton` callback. Please check the update answer. I do not know why your GUI does not work. Could it be because of the way you manage the `handles`? What is `this.gui_h.axes1`?

Comment: I updated the code, yet the image disappears. Its the extract code. The labels seem to rotate.

Comment: Its interesting that the plot is visible and rotates perfectly but not the .png I am loading.

Comment: I can not understand (and I'm sorry) why you still have problem with the image rotation, all the tests I've done  were OK. The only thing different, according to you comment is that you are using a `.png` image whilst I've used a `.jpg`. Unfortunately I will not have access to MatLab until next Saturday; I will be very surprised if the problem was the `type` of the image, nevertheless, perhaps, in the meanwhile, you could try with a `.jpg` image just to make sure.

Comment: I have tried it with a .jpg and the problem persist. Could it be a setting I need to do?